# How to add an element into inner xml attributes array and make sure it's sorted and unique

Tags: arrays, xml, sorting, unique, yq

I'm working with firewalld XML file that looking like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<zone>
  <short>Public</short>
  <description>For use in public areas. You do not trust the other computers on networks to not harm your computer. Only selected incoming connections are accepted.</description>
  <service name="ssh"></service>
  <service name="dhcpv6-client"></service>
  <service name="cockpit"></service>
  <service name="https"></service>
  <service name="http"></service>
  <port port="5000" protocol="tcp"></port>
  <port port="5001" protocol="tcp"></port>
  <port port="9999" protocol="tcp"></port>
  <port port="9998" protocol="tcp"></port>
  <rule>
    <protocol value="vrrp"></protocol>
    <accept></accept>
  </rule>
</zone>
```

I want to add several new TCP ports into it, sort them and ensure they are unique

Comment: Well what did you try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[kislyuk/yq](https://github.com/kislyuk/yq) provides the `xq` command which can be used to manipulate XML files using `jq` syntax.

For this case, just append another object (wrapped into an array) to the existing array, and apply `unique` to it (which also sorts the items). Note that the port numbers are processed as strings, so in order to have them sorted numerically, convert them for the comparisons using `tonumber`. Finally, the `-x` flag will tranform the result back into XML.

```bash
xq -x '.zone.port |= (
  . + [{"@port": "993", "@protocol": "tcp"}]
  | unique_by(."@port" | tonumber)
)' file.xml
```

```xml
<zone>
  <short>Public</short>
  <description>For use in public areas. You do not trust the other computers on networks to not harm your computer. Only selected incoming connections are accepted.</description>
  <service name="ssh"></service>
  <service name="dhcpv6-client"></service>
  <service name="cockpit"></service>
  <service name="https"></service>
  <service name="http"></service>
  <port port="993" protocol="tcp"></port>
  <port port="5000" protocol="tcp"></port>
  <port port="5001" protocol="tcp"></port>
  <port port="9998" protocol="tcp"></port>
  <port port="9999" protocol="tcp"></port>
  <rule>
    <protocol value="vrrp"></protocol>
    <accept></accept>
  </rule>
</zone>
```

If you want to add multiple entries at once, consider using `--args` to read them in as command-line arguments (available since jq 1.6):

```bash
xq -x '.zone.port |= (
  . + [$ARGS.positional | _nwise(2) | {"@port": first, "@protocol": last}]
  | unique_by(."@port" | tonumber)
)' file.xml --args 6543 tcp 210 udp
```

```xml
<zone>
  <short>Public</short>
  <description>For use in public areas. You do not trust the other computers on networks to not harm your computer. Only selected incoming connections are accepted.</description>
  <service name="ssh"></service>
  <service name="dhcpv6-client"></service>
  <service name="cockpit"></service>
  <service name="https"></service>
  <service name="http"></service>
  <port port="210" protocol="udp"></port>
  <port port="5000" protocol="tcp"></port>
  <port port="5001" protocol="tcp"></port>
  <port port="6543" protocol="tcp"></port>
  <port port="9998" protocol="tcp"></port>
  <port port="9999" protocol="tcp"></port>
  <rule>
    <protocol value="vrrp"></protocol>
    <accept></accept>
  </rule>
</zone>
```

Comment: As I understand unique will be applied only to adding ports. I need to apply it to resulting array to ensure that no ports will be duplicated. For example I want to be able to add port 6543 without checking if it already exists in the original file, and be sure that unique will eliminate it.

Comment: @lyres This is exactly what happens. We first add together `… + …` the old array `.` and the new array `[…]`, then onto the unified result `. + […] | …` we apply `unique`/`unique_by`.

Comment: Thanks a lot!
I just figured out that you uses another yq (kislyuk/yq) than I thought about (mikefarah/yq). With your help I was able to build proper script to achieve the same for that one (they have a little different syntax and also doesn't support tonumber conversion)

Comment: @lyres Yes, there are two tools called `yq` (also see the [info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/yq/info) for the `yq` tag). One (kislyuk) is a wrapper for `jq`, thus uses the proper jq language, and works by transcoding to and from JSON. The other one (mikefarah) is an independent project that transcodes to and from YAML, and uses its own DSL that is just inspired by jq, so there are a lot of similarities as well as a lot of differences.

Answer (score 0):

The answer of pmf is correct, but when I asked my question I mentioned another yq executable ([mikefarah/yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq)). This one is written in Go.
Its syntax is slightly different (latest version uses +@ as an attribute prefix and still has no 'tonumber'):

```
yq -p xml -o xml '.zone.port |= ( 
. + [{"+@port":"8500","+@protocol":"tcp"}] 
| sort_by(."+@port") 
| unique_by(."+@port" + ."+@protocol") 
)' /etc/firewalld/zones/public.xml
```

This syntax ensures that port/protocol array will be unique and sorted (as string).

Comment: mikefarah/yq indeed doesn't (yet) have a `tonumber` filter. You could mitigate this circumstance by interpreting the stringified number as YAML or JSON by using the `from_yaml` or `from_json` functions: `… | sort_by(."+@port" | from_yaml) | …`